# Auto sizing column in TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, virtualtreeview

Climbing the learning mountain of TVirtualTreeView, I'm attempting to create a custom descendant that ensures that, when the control is resized, the width of the last column exactly fills control's width without requiring a horizontal scroll bar.

I see a number of items (a method and a number of events) pertaining to "AutoFitColumns", but not documentation covering this feature.  Can I use AutoFitColumns to automatically resize my last column and if so, how.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware that the resizing doesn't happen automatically but has to be invoked manually with AutoFitColumns().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With your virtualtreeview, and a couple headers visible....

Select the "virtualtreeview | Header" in the delphi object inspector and Set the AutoSizeIndex to the the index of your last column.

Now select "virtualtreeview | Header | Options" and make sure hoAutoResize is TRUE.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I had missed the existence and meaning of AutoSizeIndex.

Comment: easiest way to do this:
vt.Header.Options := vt.Header.Options + [hoAutoResize];
vt.Header.AutoSizeIndex := vt.Header.Columns.GetLastVisibleColumn;