# TVirtualStringTree ScaleBy Stretch

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10-seattle, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I'm Trying to get a VST to resize automatically when its Height and Width is changed.
I don't have this problem with other placed VCL components, some of them have a Property "Stretch" like TImage, which lets them adjust automatically. The VST remains stubborn and keeps nodeHeights and Column widths.

- I have seen Header->hoAutoResize, hoColumnResize. In this matter, AutoSizeIndex <> -1 is not so useful, since I need every column to scale down. I think that's why these don't do anything. *Changing the AutoSizeIndex to my last Column (3, because i have 4 Columns) and having hoAutoResize = True; still doesn't affect my column widths*. hoColumnResize is the setting that lets the User resize columns, so no luck with that either
- I have seen TreeOptions->AutoOptions->toAutoChangeScale and toAutoSpanColumns. *I found out that toAutoSpanColumns is counter-productive in my case, so that's off*. My Font-Size is adjusting.
- I have found Tree.Scaleby, but I can't make it work in my favor and it's undocumented in the official .pdf docs I have.
- All 4 columns have minWidth of 10, so no issue there
- All 4 have coEnabled, coVisible, coResizable := True and coFixed, coSmartResize := False fwiw

I guess I'm just hitting the wrong combinations of settings or something.
Any hints would be great, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto sizing column in TVirtualStringTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679862/auto-sizing-column-in-tvirtualstringtree)

Comment: Auto-sizing column widths should work. Auto-Sizing node-/line-height seems like a rather unusual concept: Controls like grids and TListView and Applications like Windows Explorer or Outlook do not do this.

Comment: I just thought within the tons of options that VST has, there would be something that functionally resembles "Stretch" just with Column widths. Turns out you have to do it manually in OnResize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post I understand that you want to automatically adjust widths of all columns proportionally when the `TVirtualStringTree` width changes. If you want that to also happen with the row heights, you can just apply the following correspondingly.

There is no setting for the a propertional column width, but it is simple to achieve in the `OnResize` event of the `TVirtualStringTree`:

```
procedure TForm1.VSTResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VST.Header.Columns[0].Width := MulDiv(VST.Width, 50, 100);
  VST.Header.Columns[1].Width := MulDiv(VST.Width, 30, 100);
  VST.Header.Columns[2].Width := MulDiv(VST.Width, 20, 100);
end;
```

In the above, the columns are kept as 50%, 30% and 20% of the components width.

Comment: That works fine, Thanks. ANode: PVirtualNode; while Assigned(Anode) do begin VST.NodeHeight[ANode] := trunc(VST.Height / 16); ANode := VST.GetNextVisible(ANode); end;

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Header->AutoSizeIndex to the index of yours last column, besides the Header->hoAutoResize to true.

Something like this if you wish to do it programmatically:

```
vt.Header.Options := vt.Header.Options + [hoAutoResize];
vt.Header.AutoSizeIndex := vt.Header.Columns.GetLastVisibleColumn;
```

Comment: I edited my post. I have read the post you linked before i posted. I don't get it to work like that